# Retrieving data from Model or ViewModel for a Chart in ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor using Chart Helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, charts, razor, helper

I want to create a graphical chart in mvc 3 razor using the code below (thanks to DotNetJalps):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Helpers;

namespace CodeSimplifiedTest.Controllers
{
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult DrawChart()
    {
        var chart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 200)
            .AddSeries(
                        chartType: "bar",
                        xValue: new[] { "10 Records", "20 Records", "30 Records", "40 Records" },
                        yValues: new[] { "50", "60", "78", "80" })
                        .GetBytes("png");
        return File(chart, "image/bytes");
    }
  }
}
```

But

I want to retrieve the xValues and Yvalues from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database...what code must I put after xValue: and yValue: or some code anywhere in the controller and view to retrieve data from the database? I tried Entity Framework context...but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: That will depend on the schema of your tables and how your data is organized in this SQL database as well as what data access technology you would like to use.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i am using to make the chart from the dbContext from EF....

[image]

```
public ActionResult PayorPieChart()
{
  string xx = activePhysicianID;

  ArrayList xValue = new ArrayList();
  ArrayList yValue = new ArrayList();

  XXXXXXX_MainEntities dbContext = new XXXXXXX_MainEntities();
  var results = dbContext.Payor.Where(rs => rs.PhysicianIdentity.Equals(xx));

  results.ToList().ForEach(rs => xValue.Add(rs.Identifier));
  results.ToList().ForEach(rs => yValue.Add(rs.Strength));

  var chart = new Chart(600, 300, ChartTheme.Blue);
  chart.AddSeries(chartType: "Pie", xValue: xValue, yValues: yValue);
  chart.AddTitle("Payor");
  chart.Write("png");

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below link explains how to use "DataBindTable" method which binds the data from Model. Here, the data is framed inside the Model. You can get the data from sql server in the model inside the method "GetChartData".

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/10/10/asp-net-mvc-3-beta-built-in-support-for-charts.aspx

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I did try this site...but when I type in this part:

var model = new ChartModel();

ChartModel is underlined in red...do I have to add a reference or call something?

Comment: Did you add the model class "ChartModel" under the "Models" folder?

Comment: oh wait...i am so stupid...ChartModel is the name of any model...I already have like 15 models...i must replace "ChartModel" with the name of one of my models, right?

Comment: Yes. You are right. You have to replace that with one of the models that you have. Hope this helped you!!

Comment: wait...I spotted it...there's something that's not working:

var data = model.GetChartData();

when i enter my model name in place of "model" then type in ".GetChartData" , there is a red line underneath .GetChartData() , now why is that happening?

Comment: Check if there are any namespace issues which might cause the error that you have specified.